# How do I add a decimal onto all strings in a list?

Tags: linux

I have a list that looks like this:

```
1929384
1240596
1339588
1349503
1948530
...
```

I want to add a decimal point so that it looks like this:

```
1929384.1
1240596.1
1339588.1
1349503.1
1948530.1
...
```

Is there a quick command in linux to do this?

Comment: Is this a file in linux?

Comment: Do you want just to append .1 at the end of each input line?

Comment: yes that would be great - I have a list like this as a text file, just want to append .1 to the end. Is there a quick one liner to do this?

Comment: You should read some kind of Unix tutorial. For example http://evomics.org/learning/unix-tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

```
sed "s/\([0-9]\)$/\1.1/g"
```

In particular, if your list is contained in a dummy.txt file, you can do as following:

```
sed "s/\([0-9]\)$/\1.1/g" dummy.txt > output.txt
```

Explanation:

1. `\([0-9]\)$` Matches the last digit of the line. Use parenthesis operator to save digit (see point 2). `$` Matches end of line. Matching one digit is just to ensure we do not add `.1` to empty lines, for example.
2. `\1` In the substitution expression, place back the string matched at point 1 (puts back the last digit of the line)
3. `.1` The desired appended `.1`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` like this:

```
sed 's/$/.1/' list.txt
```

`$` matches the end of the line.